# Identity server 4 and Angular app authenticate to achieve forever lasting session

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4

Current structure:
I have angular app as Client, API as data source and Identity server as Identity source. In angular I authenticate user against identity server and use returned token to authorize user against API. Which Grant type should I use to authenticate my angular app user against identity server? 
 According to http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/grant_types.html, I should use Implicit grant type.

Problem is that with Implicit grant type there are no refresh tokens. So my question is, how should I keep my user session alive in angular app (access token valid) ? - without asking user to authenticate himself after every time access token gets expired.

My goal is to have session alive (token valid) until its killed by user (logged out)

Comment: if you have a requirement like, you will have to revoke the user session in any case !!! thats going to be a bit of a pain. try to have some control over user session.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Implicit flow is the one I would use. If your authentication provider supports sessions, you can use OpenID Connect to get new tokens without user interaction. Before the token expiration, create an authentication request (`/auth` endpoint) in a hidden iframe with `prompt=none` URL parameter (`id_token_hint=...` parameter should be present too according to the [OpenID Connect RFC](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html)). If the user session is open, you will get new tokens, otherwise error is returned (user interaction required).

There is the [OpenID Connect Session Management](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html) RFC that describes this process and more (single sign on).